# How to include new idl files and compiling them in Redhawk sdr source code

Tags: makefile, idl, redhawksdr

I want to place files a.idl, b.idl in the folder at the link https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/tree/master/src/idl/ossie/CF

And I also include a.idl and b.idl in the makefile at this link
 https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/tree/master/src/idl
As is done for all other idl file mentioned above.
But these are not compiled as I am not able to see them anywhere.

Please provide any inputs

Answer (score 1):

In addition to including, a.idl and b.idl in the file "Makefile.am" at this link https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/tree/master/src/idl , we have to do the following in the "Makefile.am" present at the link https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/tree/master/src/base/framework/idl

1. Add aSK.cpp, aDynSK.cpp, bSK.cpp, bDynSK.cpp to the "BUILT_SOURCES" variable defined in the file.

With this done, now we can see the skeleton and stub codes in the folders at following links :
https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/framework-core/tree/master/src/base/framework/idl
and
 this folder which will be generated on running the install command  "RedhawkSDR/framework-core/tree/master/src/base/include/ossie/CF/"

Answer (score 0):

REDHAWK's IDL is split into two main categories: core services and ports. Core services are related to REDHAWK's core functionality, like deploying an application. Ports are application-specific interfaces for communicating between different processing stages (components or devices). Core services are not meant to be extended, while ports are meant to be extended by the user beyond those already provided (see https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.4/manual/connections/)

New IDL can be added to a REDHAWK instance by creating custom IDL interfaces (https://redhawksdr.github.io/2.2.4/manual/connections/custom-idl-interfaces/)

Comment: I understand your point. What I am trying to do is upgrade core framework of Redhawk SCA from SCA 2.2.2 partial to SCA 4.1 and this is also done partially by GEONTECH at the following link  https://github.com/Geontech/sca-jtnc